# Sitecore User Group Conference - Europe 2022

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

[image: SUGCON logo]

**More info: https://europe.sugcon.events/**

The Sitecore User Group Conference brings the Sitecore user community together and provides the perfect platform to gain knowledge and get inspired by the potential within Sitecore Managed Cloud, Sitecore Headless, CDP, Content Hub, Sitecore Send, OrderCloud and more.

**Venue:** [Budapest Congress Center](https://europe.sugcon.events/Venue) (Budapest, Jagelló út 1-3, 1123, Hungary)

**When:** March 24th - March 25th, 2022

**Tickets:** https://europe.sugcon.events/Registration - **You can also sign up for a Sitecore certification exam at a discounted price!**

Comment: You can also sign up for a certification exam at a discounted price.